# Pyinstaller Error?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Before including cefpython, pyinstaller works as expected and generate exec file. I am new to this technology I don't know why this error getting because of pyinstaller problem or any other issues.

Is anything other than pyinstaller available to generate the exec in ubuntu?

**Version using:**

```
CEF Python 57.0
Python 2.7.12 64bit
wxPython 4.0.0b2 gtk2 (phoenix)
```

**Create Exec file:**

```
ex: pyinstaller --onefile wxpython.py
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wxpython.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cefpython3/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 136, in __init__
  File "ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
OSError: /tmp/_MEInJSebh/cefpython3/libcef.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to execute script wxpython
```

Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: cx_freeze may be an alternative to generate an executable from a Python script. See this post for other alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @apogalacticon I have tried with cx_freeze. If I run getting  `ImportError: No module named __startup__`. When I build got all dependencies related application, should I copy all build file to bin directory or Is it enough to copy exec file?

Comment: maybe you opened the executable from another `cwd` that the executable was `expecting` and that is why it doesnt see the file or maybe you need to fallback the pyinstaller version.

Comment: What does this command return? `sudo find / -name libcef.so` In case it does not find the file, you should simply install it. In case it DOES find the file, you could try to use pyinstaller's `--add-data` option and add the licef.so